# Appium:some button click() not working in android

Tags: android, button, click, appium

I am performing automation testing on eBay android application. First, I need to automate login in eBay then I want to  proceed with checkout.

I am able to automate login in eBay except one button i.e. *SIGN IN*(this button redirect user to login screen). All Other button clicks are working but SIGN IN button click is not working.

Here is my code.

```
private static void executeLoginFlow() {
    // This is not working
    MobileElement loginButton = ((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver)
            .findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.ebay.mobile:id/button_sign_in\")");
    loginButton.click();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // This is working
    MobileElement emailEditText = ((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(
            "new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.ebay.mobile:id/edit_text_username\")");
    emailEditText.clear();
    emailEditText.setValue("abc@xyz.com");

    driver.hideKeyboard();

    ((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).pressKeyCode(66);

    // // This is working
    MobileElement passwordEditText = ((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver).findElementByAndroidUIAutomator(
            "new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.ebay.mobile:id/edit_text_password\")");
    passwordEditText.clear();
    passwordEditText.setValue("123456789");

    driver.hideKeyboard();
    // This also working
    MobileElement mainLoginButton = ((AndroidDriver<MobileElement>) driver)
            .findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.ebay.mobile:id/button_sign_in\")");
    mainLoginButton.click();
}
```

I am using **java-client-5.0.0.jar**.

Here is snapshot from Uiautomatorviewer.
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the error log?

Comment: No stacktrace coming. noting coming on console,otherwise I could have posted it.

Comment: Why are you having to cast your driver in each reference?  What is it initialized to?  Consider using `AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>` It might not make a difference but worth a try.  Also, I'd not use that locator method, I'd use something like `driver.findElement(By.id("..."))` which works fine for me.